# DFT of vector $(0, 1, 2, 3)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, vectors

The problem is that my answer is different from answer i get in MATLAB.

My answer is $(6, -2-2i, -2, -2+2i)$ while MATLAB answer is $(6, -2+2i, -2, -2-2i).$ In MATLAB i use command `fft([0 1 2 3]).`

How do i compute: $y_1 = 1w_4^1 + 2w_4^2 + 3w_4^3 = i - 2 - 3i = -2-2i$

EDIT: Thanks to **par** i found out that in MATLAB $ω_n=e^{(−2πi)/n}$ while i use $ω_n=e^{(2πi)/n}.$ So, solved.

Comment: MATLAB might order the DFT differently than you do (notice that you have the same numbers, just in different places). The DFT they compute is given here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html. Check if it agrees with your own formulation.

Comment: Let $DFT((0,1,2,3)) = (X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3)$ then using the definition of DFT we get that $X_0 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6$, $X_1 = 0 + i + -2 + -3i = -2-2i$, $X_2 = 0 + -1 + 2 + -3 = -2$, $X_3 = 0 + -i + -2 + 3i = -2 + 2i$ so your calculations seem correct. As @par suggested check the documentation for fft and also for the function fftshift

Comment: Using $e^{-i\cdot\text{bla}}$ is really standard for the forward transformation, so Matlab is not to blame ;)